# Powershell: Out-File with Headers/Columns

Tags: powershell

I am very close to what I am looking for, I have all of the correct data and it is just not formatting correctly.  Currently it is all in one column, and what I would like is for the headers to be in a row, and then each entry to be in its own row as well.  Here is my current code:

```
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like 'f****p*'" | Sort-Object | Select -ExpandProperty Name

$servers | foreach {

$server = $_
$serverIP = Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 | Select -ExpandProperty IPV4Address
$serverIPString = $serverIP.IPAddresstoString
$scope = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $server
$options = Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue -ComputerName $server

New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{

    ServerName = $server
    ServerIP = $serverIPString
    ScopeName = $scope.Name | Out-String
    StartIP = $scope.StartRange.IPAddressToString | Out-String
    EndIP = $scope.EndRange.IPAddressToString | Out-String
    SubnetMask = $scope.SubnetMask.IPAddressToString | Out-String
    Duration = $scope.LeaseDuration.Days | Out-String
    OptionName = $options.Name | Out-String
    OptionID = $options.OptionID | Out-String
    OptionValue = $options.Value | Out-String

    }

} | Select-Object ServerName, ServerIP, ScopeName, StartIP, EndIP, SubnetMask, Duration, OptionName, OptionID, OptionValue | Out-File C:\temp\FPScopes.csv
```

Currently the output looks like this example (using Duration and Options as an example, as it has the most generic data to share):

[image]

What I am looking for would be to have each object type as a column header, and have the entries in a separate row underneath the header:

[image]

Etc....

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!  :)
Ry

My final code, after help from this forum:

```
Add-Content -Value "ServerName,ServerIP,ScopeName,StartRange,EndRange,SubnetMask,Duration,OptionName,OptionID,Value" -Path c:\temp\POSScopes.csv

Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like 'p****p01' -or Name -like 'p****p02' -or Name -like 'q****001' -or Name -like 'q****002'} | Sort-Object | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File C:\Temp\POSServers.txt

$servers = Get-Content C:\Temp\POSServers.txt

$servers | foreach {

$server = $_
$serverIP = Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 | Select -ExpandProperty IPV4Address
$serverIPString = $serverIP.IPAddresstoString
$scope = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $server
$options = Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue -ComputerName $server

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{

        ServerName = $server
        ServerIP = $serverIPString
        ScopeName = $scope.Name | Out-String
        StartIP = $scope.StartRange.IPAddressToString | Out-String
        EndIP = $scope.EndRange.IPAddressToString | Out-String
        SubnetMask = $scope.SubnetMask.IPAddressToString | Out-String
        Duration = $scope.LeaseDuration.Days | Out-String
        OptionName = $options.Name | Out-String
        OptionID = $options.OptionID | Out-String
        OptionValue = $options.Value | Out-String

}


for ($i = ($Options.Count -1); $i -gt -1; $i--) {

Add-Content -Value "$($server),$($serverIPString),$($scope.Name),$($scope.StartRange.IPAddressToString),$($scope.EndRange.IPAddressToString),$($scope.SubnetMask.IPAddressToString),$($scope.LeaseDuration.Days),$($options[$i].Name),$($options[$i].OptionID),$($Options[$i].Value)" -Path C:\temp\POSScopes.csv

    } 

}
```

Comment: A simple `ConvertTo-CSV` ought to do the trick.

Comment: Bryce is close; use `Export-Csv` rather than `Out-File` (and don't forget the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter).

Comment: Or, instead of `Out-File`, use `Export-CSV`.

Comment: Hi, I added this to my last line of code, it did not seem to help - still everything is in one column (and now a bit jumbled) - did I add the command in the wrong place?  Select-Object ServerName, ServerIP, ScopeName, StartIP, EndIP, SubnetMask, Duration, OptionName, OptionID, OptionValue | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File C:\temp\FPScopes.csv

Comment: Hi @Bill_Stewart - I tried that originally, but it truncates a lot of my output if I use Export-csv.  Any ideas?

Comment: `Export-Csv` doesn't truncate anything.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - maybe truncate is not the right word, but for instance, where there are multiple scopes on a server, it would only export the first scope and it's configurations to the .csv, when using export-csv.  Whereas when I use out-file, I see all of the scopes, options and configs.

Comment: Try this for the properties that have multiple entries:

`OptionName = ($options | select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ", " | Out-String`

Comment: @T4RH33L - unfortunately, that did not help.

Comment: @LilithGoddess Is that because you expect each value for each property to be listed under each computer?  I believe you would have to write some sort of `For-Each` statement that runs against your collection of results.  This will give you a single line for each value, but it will most likely repeat much of the same data.  What is your end game with this data?  Maybe if we know how it is to be used we can come up with a better plan.

Comment: @T4RH33L - you bet, and I think that could be the right track.  Basically I am running this report so that I can look at any discrepancies between scope configurations on the servers.  So ideally, I could sort and filter this information as needed.  For each machine, I would want to see all of the scopes, their configurations, their options, and the configurations for those options.  :)

Comment: @LilithGoddess You are looking to do something that is beyond my skill.  I've actually tried to do just what you are looking for and have had no luck.  That's why I settled on using the `-join` switch.  With a lot of looping and creating several custom objects you can get close to what you want but it won't be neat as the output from the console.

Comment: Check out [this blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/poshchap/2015/10/02/create-a-csv-report-of-dhcp-scope-options/) and see if they're accomplishing what you want to do. It looks very similar.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - that link was actually quite helpful, thank you.  I am going to post my final code here so that it may help others with similar goals.  :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Add-Content -Value "ServerName,ServerIP,ScopeName,StartRange,EndRange,SubnetMask,Duration,OptionName,OptionID,Value" -Path c:\temp\POSScopes.csv

Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like 'p****p01' -or Name -like 'p****p02' -or Name -like 'q****001' -or Name -like 'q****002'} | Sort-Object | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File C:\Temp\POSServers.txt

$servers = Get-Content C:\Temp\POSServers.txt

$servers | foreach {

$server = $_
$serverIP = Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Count 1 | Select -ExpandProperty IPV4Address
$serverIPString = $serverIP.IPAddresstoString
$scope = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $server
$options = Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue -ComputerName $server

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{

        ServerName = $server
        ServerIP = $serverIPString
        ScopeName = $scope.Name | Out-String
        StartIP = $scope.StartRange.IPAddressToString | Out-String
        EndIP = $scope.EndRange.IPAddressToString | Out-String
        SubnetMask = $scope.SubnetMask.IPAddressToString | Out-String
        Duration = $scope.LeaseDuration.Days | Out-String
        OptionName = $options.Name | Out-String
        OptionID = $options.OptionID | Out-String
        OptionValue = $options.Value | Out-String

}


for ($i = ($Options.Count -1); $i -gt -1; $i--) {

Add-Content -Value "$($server),$($serverIPString),$($scope.Name),$($scope.StartRange.IPAddressToString),$($scope.EndRange.IPAddressToString),$($scope.SubnetMask.IPAddressToString),$($scope.LeaseDuration.Days),$($options[$i].Name),$($options[$i].OptionID),$($Options[$i].Value)" -Path C:\temp\POSScopes.csv

    } 

}
```